# fragment transaction not working

Tags: java, android

i am trying to create a transaction between two fragments:

frag a has the following code on it's on item selected:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        RecipesTypeList item = mRecipesTypesListAdapter.getItem(position);
        Log.d("yzeek", "" + position);

        mBundle.putInt("rTypeId",item.getRtypeID());
                fRecipeList.setArguments(mBundle);
        fRecipeList.setTitle("test");


        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fRecipeList);
        transaction.addToBackStack("");
        transaction.commit();

    //  getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle(item.getRtypeName());
        //getActivity().getActionBar().setIcon(item.getActioBarIcon());
    }
```

both fragments have a container in their XML layout.

however, when i click on a button the transaction is not performed and i dont get any error on the debugger.

does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Is the function running at all, can you see the `Log.d("yzeek", "" + position);`? If not, possibly something else is consuming the clicks and you need to show the code where you set up the item click handler.

Comment: yest it does, i cant see it in the log and see a subtitle changed on the action bard

Comment: If you're not placing `Fragment` inside `Fragment`, then you don't need `getChildFragmentManager()`. Replace it with either `getSupportFragmentManager()` or `getFragmentManager()`, depending on your base `Fragment` class

Answer (score 0):

```
 FragRecordSongList FragRecordSongList = new FragRecordSongList();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.addToBackStack(FragRecordSongList.class.getName());
        ft.replace(R.id.fragContainer, FragRecordSongList, FragRecordSongList.class.getName());
        ft.commit();
```

Try this may be this work